# Eval(function) confusion

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import random
a=random.randrange(100,400)
b=0
c=100
d=200
e=300
f=400
g=500
points =("b","c","d","e","f","g")
randomadd=random.randrange(1,500)
linepoints2=(b,305),(c,a),(d,305),(e,305),(f,a),(g,305),(g,300),(f,a+5),(e,300),(d,300),(c,a+5),(b,300)
thingy=points[random.randrange(1,len(points))]
eval(thingy) +=100
```

I want to eval() thingy as I thought it would work as it returns a string, however apparently you cannot eval() a function call, I have no idea how to get around this please help...

Answer (score 2):

`thingy` is *not* a function, is a string, so you can't evaluate it as if it were a function. If it *were* a function, you'd evaluate it like this:

```
eval("thingy()")
```

What are you trying to do? The code is confusing, maybe you're trying to do something else but the way you're doing it is wrong.

**EDIT :**

Now that it's clear what you intended to do, I can suggest you to use a dictionary, it will work as a "variable" (there's no need to *eval* anything, that's not the correct approach to solve your problem):

```
d = {}
d[thingy] = 100
d[thingy] += 200
d[thingy]
> 300
```

Comment: Hang on... I know it is a string but I wanted to turn it into a varible name so I could change whichever out of bcdefg 's values it came up with but I seem unable to do that...

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look at it, I believe it's what you intended in the first place

Comment: @RPGer Please don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful for you (click the check mark to its left), I've noticed that you've _never_ accepted any answer in the site, and people will be less likely to help you if you don't accept their answers.

Answer (score 1):

Err, what are you trying to do over here?

```
# bad
eval(thingy) +=100
```

That translates to:

```
# bad
eval(thingy) = eval(thingy) + 100
```

And you can't assign to a function call (I think *that* was the error you were getting).

You can do something like:

```
# good
result = eval(thingy) + 100
```

Which seems to work perfectly (result = 400).

Comment: RPGer: if this solved your problem, you can always click the check mark on the left to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: This function seems to result in a random point -- how do you want to "edit" one of the original variables? For example, if it randomly decides to use 'd', d = 200, so it will print 200. What variable do you want to assign?

Answer (score 1):

As one of your comment suggests you wanna edit the original variable, so try this instead of `eval()`:

```
vars()[thingy]+=100
```

or as [ZyX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273566/zyx) suggested use `locals()`:

```
locals()[thingy]+=100
```

Comment: I am surprised that there is only one of four answers mentioning this, though I would rather use `locals()` here: it is a complete equivalent for `vars()` without arguments. No offense: I just did not knew about `vars()`.

Comment: thanks I never knew about `locals()`, and I used `vars()` without arguments(as a dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

Even better - avoid eval() altogether. Try

```
from random import randrange, choice

points = (
    randrange(100,400),
    0,
    100,
    200,
    300,
    400,
    500
)

result = choice(points) + 100
```